# Using 'failover partner' property of connection string to failover to a non-mirror database

Tags: .net, sql-server, database-mirroring

Our application needs to use a different (stripped down) version of the principal database if it becomes unavailable. The backup database will have the same structure and objects as the principal, some tables will just have less data.

Is there a way to set up the DB mirror in such a way that no real mirroring takes place but the 'failover partner' property of the .NET connection string can still be used to connect to another database without getting 'database is not configured for mirroring' error?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or try DNS Failover i.e. swap the hostnames of Principal servers in DNS server.

Answer (score 0):

No. To use database mirroring features (ie. 'failover partner' in connection string) you need to deploy database mirroring.

Obviously, if you need to fail over to a standby database if the principal is not available, then you should use... database mirroring.

Comment: For security reasons we can't have the full data set in the standby DB. We can have the bare minimum for the application to start up. So mirroring doesn't really work for us. We just want to leverage the failover part of the mirroring configuration, without actually moving any data between databases.